# Importing a web application onto Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)

Tags: eclipse

I have a web application in a folder that has tons of HTML , CSS, JS files with all the stuff that goes into building one...the task runners, package managers, all the files related to them...
This is my first time trying to import a web app onto eclipse...can anyone help me with doing it?

Answer (score 0):

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av6zh817QEc**
take a look might get an idea

Comment: I dont see any JSP related files in the folder...its all html, css and js files only...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a New Project --> Dynamic Web Project for the Web application. Import the folders in the project or copy the folders into the respective folder hierarchy like HTML, CSS, JS inside the WebContent folder.